# Imputing missing values using mutate_if and applying an imputation function

Tags: r

I have some time series data with missing values. I would like to apply a function to impute the missing values but I get an error. I would like to apply the function to to all columns where it finds an NA value.

```
    library(quantmod)
library(imputeTS)
getSymbols("GOOG")

GOOG[sample(nrow(GOOG), 100), ] <- NA   # Create some missing values

GOOG %>% 
  mutate_if(~any(is.na(.x)), ~na_kalman(., model = "StructTS"))


library(bnstruct)
GOOG %>% 
  mutate_if(~any(is.na(.x), ~knn.impute(k = 5)))
```

I understand that the `na_kalman` should be used on structured time series data but is it possible to use it on `tbls`.

> Error in UseMethod("tbl_vars") :    no applicable method for
>   'tbl_vars' applied to an object of class "c('xts', 'zoo')"

Comment: did you figure this out?

Comment: I think, simply putting it to a `data.frame` first and then running the `mutate_if` function should work. `x <- GOOG %>%
  data.frame() %>% 
  mutate_if(~any(is.na(.x)), ~na_kalman(., model = "StructTS"))`